# Resultados repetidos al ejecutar un cursor en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

Tengo una función en MySQL que tiene un cursor. Por las comparaciones en sybase debe devolver dos resultados, pero me devuelve 3 ya que el segundo que retorna lo repite. ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Os dejo el código de la función:

```
delimiter //
create function dba.fn_atl_sap_fac_imp(vCOD_CLI_FAC decimal(30,6), vID_FAC bigint(30)) returns text
begin
DECLARE ID_IVA CHAR(2);
DECLARE vIMP_IVA CHAR(15);
DECLARE BASE_IVA CHAR(15);
DECLARE IMPORTE_FACTURADO DEC(20, 6);
DECLARE importe_facturado_iva DEC(20, 6);
DECLARE DIFERENCIA DEC(20, 6);
DECLARE numero int;
DECLARE return_Impuesto long VARCHAR;
declare FIN int;


DECLARE csr_IVA_FAC_PAR CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 
        concat(replace(space(2-length(iva.ID_IVA_SAP)), ' ', '0') , iva.ID_IVA_SAP),
        concat(replace(space(15-length(convert(i.IMP_IVA*100,signed))), ' ', '0'),convert(i.IMP_IVA*100,signed)),
        concat(replace(space(15-length(convert(i.BASE_IVA*100,signed))), ' ', '0'),convert(i.BASE_IVA*100,signed))
        FROM IVA_FAC_PAR i
            join IVA on (iva.id_iva = i.id_iva)
        WHERE #IVA_FAC_PAR.COD_CLI_FAC=vCOD_CLI_FAC AND 
            i.ID_FAC=vID_FAC;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET FIN = 1;

set return_Impuesto='';
set numero=0;

SELECT 
    IMP_FAC
INTO IMPORTE_FACTURADO FROM
    FAC_PAR
WHERE
    FAC_PAR.ID_FAC = vID_FAC;


SELECT 
    SUM(i.IMP_IVA + i.BASE_IVA)
INTO importe_facturado_iva FROM
    IVA_FAC_PAR i
WHERE
    i.ID_FAC = vID_FAC;


SET DIFERENCIA = IMPORTE_FACTURADO - importe_facturado_iva;


OPEN csr_IVA_FAC_PAR;

CICLO:loop
        IF FIN THEN
            LEAVE CICLO;
        END IF;
FETCH csr_IVA_FAC_PAR into ID_IVA, vIMP_IVA, BASE_IVA;

IF DIFERENCIA <> 0 THEN
    SET vIMP_IVA = vIMP_IVA/100;
    SET vIMP_IVA = vIMP_IVA + DIFERENCIA;
    SET vIMP_IVA=concat(replace(space(15-length(convert(vIMP_IVA*100,signed))), ' ', '0'),convert(vIMP_IVA*100,signed));
    SET DIFERENCIA = 0;
END IF;

SET numero= numero + 1;

SET return_Impuesto = concat(return_Impuesto,'T ', ID_IVA , vIMP_IVA , BASE_IVA , ';');  


end loop CICLO;
CLOSE csr_IVA_FAC_PAR;

return return_Impuesto;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Debe de ser que en el cursor verificas primero el estado del cursor y despues haces el fetch de los datos, por eso siempre se repite el ultimo registro, se deberia solucionar cambiando de lugar la linea del fetch arriba del IF:

```
 delimiter //
create
function dba.fn_atl_sap_fac_imp(vCOD_CLI_FAC decimal(30, 6), vID_FAC bigint(30)) returns text
begin
DECLARE ID_IVA CHAR(2);
DECLARE vIMP_IVA CHAR(15);
DECLARE BASE_IVA CHAR(15);
DECLARE IMPORTE_FACTURADO DEC(20, 6);
DECLARE importe_facturado_iva DEC(20, 6);
DECLARE DIFERENCIA DEC(20, 6);
DECLARE numero int;
DECLARE return_Impuesto long VARCHAR;
declare FIN int;


DECLARE csr_IVA_FAC_PAR CURSOR FOR
SELECT
concat(replace(space(2 - length(iva.ID_IVA_SAP)), ' ', '0'), iva.ID_IVA_SAP),
    concat(replace(space(15 - length(convert(i.IMP_IVA * 100, signed))), ' ', '0'), convert(i.IMP_IVA * 100, signed)),
    concat(replace(space(15 - length(convert(i.BASE_IVA * 100, signed))), ' ', '0'), convert(i.BASE_IVA * 100, signed))
FROM IVA_FAC_PAR i
join IVA on(iva.id_iva = i.id_iva)
WHERE# IVA_FAC_PAR.COD_CLI_FAC = vCOD_CLI_FAC AND
i.ID_FAC = vID_FAC;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
SET FIN = 1;

set return_Impuesto = '';
set numero = 0;

SELECT
IMP_FAC
INTO IMPORTE_FACTURADO FROM
FAC_PAR
WHERE
FAC_PAR.ID_FAC = vID_FAC;


SELECT
SUM(i.IMP_IVA + i.BASE_IVA)
INTO importe_facturado_iva FROM
IVA_FAC_PAR i
WHERE
i.ID_FAC = vID_FAC;


SET DIFERENCIA = IMPORTE_FACTURADO - importe_facturado_iva;


OPEN csr_IVA_FAC_PAR;
FETCH csr_IVA_FAC_PAR into ID_IVA, vIMP_IVA, BASE_IVA;

CICLO: loop
IF FIN THEN
LEAVE CICLO;
END IF;


IF DIFERENCIA < > 0 THEN
SET vIMP_IVA = vIMP_IVA / 100;
SET vIMP_IVA = vIMP_IVA + DIFERENCIA;
SET vIMP_IVA = concat(replace(space(15 - length(convert(vIMP_IVA * 100, signed))), ' ', '0'), convert(vIMP_IVA * 100, signed));
SET DIFERENCIA = 0;
END IF;

SET numero = numero + 1;

SET return_Impuesto = concat(return_Impuesto, 'T ', ID_IVA, vIMP_IVA, BASE_IVA, ';');


end loop CICLO;
CLOSE csr_IVA_FAC_PAR;
```

> Fetch MYSQL : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetch.html

Comment: muchas gracias!!